# Boxplot multiindex

Tags: python, boxplot, multi-index

I want to do a plot (boxplot) of the returns of a MultiIndex df looking like this:

```
                   pct_change   close    high      low          open    
date       ticker                       
1999-05-04  BAC   0.123123    35.218750  36.4375    35.062500   36.437500   
            C     0.002312    361.25000  377.5000   360.625000  375.625000  
            COF   0.023321    56.416668  57.3750    55.895832   56.833332
```

I tried this: but didn't work.

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9, 6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

bp = ax.boxplot(df.unstack(level=1)['pct_change'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method from pandas to transform your dataframe into a single level.

After that you can simply plot the dataframe `df.boxplot`